# VBA Excel convert "/" string to division and others

Tags: vba, excel

In VBA Excel I want to do the following

The range `A1` contains the value `val1,/,val2`.I want to have a function that calcultates the formula stated in the following way:

```
Sub CalculateFormula()
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    splitFormula = split(.range("A1").value,",")
    debug.print splitFormula(0) / splitFormula(2)
End With
End Sub
```

where the `/` sign in the sub is dynamic so that if a put a `+ -` or `*` instead in `A1`, it will perform that operation in place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Evaluate() should do the job:

```
Sub CalculateFormula()
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    splitFormula = Split(.Range("A1").Value, ",")
    Debug.Print Application.Evaluate(splitFormula(0) & splitFormula(1) & splitFormula(2))
End With
End Sub
```